# Bootstrap AngularJS carousel: how to let slides cover full page width?

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm implementing my first angular.js web site (mobile compatible).
I use bootstrap ui carousel.
I would like to create a carousel whose slides occupy the whole page width (as in this example: [create-sleek-custom-page-bootstrap](http://www.creativebloq.com/web-design/create-sleek-custom-page-bootstrap-9134283), no demo, sorry... The example uses bootstrap, but not angularjs...).
My carousel template is the standard one:

```
<carousel interval="interval">
  <slide ng-repeat="slide in slides" active="slide.active">
    <img ng-src="{{slide.image}}" style="margin: auto;">
  </slide>
</carousel>
```

Should I include the carousel inside a container? I really can't understand...

*P.S.*: I would also like to be able to implement the sleek navbar in the example, i.e.. floating on top of the page...

Comment: Have you tried `background-size:cover;` in your CSS by any chance?

Comment: Yes, I did try it as a style of carousel...

Comment: Then maybe it's something with your markup. Could you give us a bit of your code?

Comment: @morespace54: yes, of course... I didn't do it before because I'm currently using quite standard code, from tutorials and samples on the web... However, it's public on github: https://github.com/marcolino/bb... I'm trying to set up a demo site from github right now...

Comment: Sorry, I had to move http://github.com/marcolino/bb to http://github.com/marcolino/ang-news...